# Comparing three data structures for dealing with probability distributions in Java

Tags: java, performance, random, comparative-review

**Introduction**

Suppose you are given three elements \$a, b, c\$ with respective weights \$1, 1, 3\$. Now, a probability distribution data structures will return upon request \$a\$ with probability 20%, \$b\$ with probability 20%, and \$c\$ with probability 60%.

The API for my probability distribution data structures is defined by the following abstract class:

```
package net.coderodde.stat;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements an abstract base class for probability distributions. 
 * Elements are added with strictly positive weights and whenever asking this 
 * data structure for a random element, their respective weights are taken into 
 * account. For example, if this data structure contains three different 
 * elements (<tt>a</tt>, <tt>b</tt>, <tt>c</tt> with respective weights 
 * <tt>1.0</tt>, <tt>1.0</tt>, <tt>3.0</tt>), whenever asking for a random 
 * element, there is 20 percent chance of obtaining <tt>a</tt>, 20 percent 
 * chance of obtaining <tt>b</tt>, and 60 percent chance of obtaining 
 * <tt>c</tt>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 11, 2016)
 */
public abstract class AbstractProbabilityDistribution<E> {

    /**
     * The amount of elements in this probability distribution.
     */
    protected int size;

    /**
     * The sum of all weights.
     */
    protected double totalWeight; 

    /**
     * The random number generator of this probability distribution.
     */
    protected final Random random;

    /**
     * Constructs this probability distribution.
     */
    protected AbstractProbabilityDistribution() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    /**
     * Constructs this probability distribution using the input random number 
     * generator.
     * 
     * @param random the random number generator.
     */
    protected AbstractProbabilityDistribution(final Random random) {
        this.random = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(random, 
                                       "The random number generator is null.");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the element {@code element} to this probability distribution, and
     * assigns {@code weight} as its weight.
     * 
     * @param element the element to add.
     * @param weight  the weight of the new element.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} only if the input element did not reside in this
     *         structure and was successfully added.
     */
    public abstract boolean addElement(final E element, final double weight);

    /**
     * Returns a randomly chosen element from this probability distribution 
     * taking the weights into account.
     * 
     * @return a randomly chosen element.
     */
    public abstract E sampleElement();

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if this probability distribution contains the
     * element {@code element}.
     * 
     * @param element the element to query.
     * @return {@code true} if the input element is in this probability 
     *         distribution; {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public abstract boolean contains(final E element);

    /**
     * Removes the element {@code element} from this probability distribution.
     * 
     * @param element the element to remove.
     * @return {@code true} if the element was present in this probability 
     *         distribution and was successfully removed.
     */
    public abstract boolean removeElement(final E element);

    /**
     * Removes all elements from this probability distribution.
     */
    public abstract void clear();

    /**
     * Checks that the element weight is valid. The weight must not be a 
     * <tt>NaN</tt> and must be positive, but not a positive infinity.
     * 
     * @param weight the weight to validate.
     */
    protected void checkWeight(final double weight) {
        if (Double.isNaN(weight)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The element weight is NaN.");
        }

        if (weight <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The element weight must be positive. Received " + weight);
        }

        if (Double.isInfinite(weight)) {
            // Once here, 'weight' is positive infinity.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The element weight is infinite.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that this probability distribution contains at least one element.
     */
    protected void checkNotEmpty() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "This probability distribution is empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementations**

The first probability distribution data structure relies on arrays. It has following running times:

- element addition in ammortized constant time,
- element removal in worst-case linear time,
- element sampling in worst-case linear time.

The data structure follows:

**ArrayProbabilityDistribution.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.stat.support;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.stat.AbstractProbabilityDistribution;

/**
 * This class implements a probability distribution relying on an array of 
 * elements. The running times are as follows:
 * 
 * <table>
 * <tr><td>Method</td>  <td>Complexity</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>addElement   </tt> </td>  <td>amortized constant time,</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>sampleElement</tt> </td>  <td><tt>O(n)</tt>,</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>removeElement</tt> </td>  <td><tt>O(n)</tt>.</td></tr>
 * </table>
 * 
 * @param <E> the actual type of the elements stored in this probability 
 *            distribution.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 11, 2016)
 */
public class ArrayProbabilityDistribution<E> 
extends AbstractProbabilityDistribution<E> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_STORAGE_ARRAYS_CAPACITY = 8;

    private Object[] objectStorageArray;
    private double[] weightStorageArray;
    private final Set<E> filterSet = new HashSet<>();

    public ArrayProbabilityDistribution() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    public ArrayProbabilityDistribution(final Random random) {
        super(random);
        this.objectStorageArray = new Object[DEFAULT_STORAGE_ARRAYS_CAPACITY];
        this.weightStorageArray = new double[DEFAULT_STORAGE_ARRAYS_CAPACITY];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addElement(final E element, final double weight) {
        checkWeight(weight);

        if (filterSet.contains(element)) {
            // 'element' is already present in this probability distribution.
            return false;
        }

        ensureCapacity(this.size + 1);
        objectStorageArray[this.size] = element;
        weightStorageArray[this.size] = weight; 
        this.totalWeight += weight;
        this.size++;
        this.filterSet.add(element);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public E sampleElement() {
        checkNotEmpty();
        double value = this.random.nextDouble() * this.totalWeight;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; ++i) {
            if (value < this.weightStorageArray[i]) {
                return (E) this.objectStorageArray[i];
            }

            value -= this.weightStorageArray[i];
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(final E element) {
        if (!this.filterSet.contains(element)) {
            return false;
        }

        final int index = indexOf(element);
        this.totalWeight -= this.weightStorageArray[index];

        for (int j = index + 1; j < this.size; ++j) {
            objectStorageArray[j - 1] = objectStorageArray[j];
            weightStorageArray[j - 1] = weightStorageArray[j];
        }

        objectStorageArray[--this.size] = null;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; ++i) {
            objectStorageArray[i] = null;
        }

        this.size = 0; 
        this.totalWeight = 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        return this.filterSet.contains(element);
    }

    private int indexOf(final E element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; ++i) {
            if (Objects.equals(element, this.objectStorageArray[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private void ensureCapacity(final int requestedCapacity) {
        if (requestedCapacity > objectStorageArray.length) {
            final int newCapacity = Math.max(requestedCapacity, 
                                             2 * objectStorageArray.length);
            final Object[] newObjectStorageArray = new Object[newCapacity];
            final double[] newWeightStorageArray = new double[newCapacity];

            System.arraycopy(this.objectStorageArray, 
                             0, 
                             newObjectStorageArray, 
                             0, 
                             this.size);

            System.arraycopy(this.weightStorageArray,
                             0,
                             newWeightStorageArray, 
                             0,
                             this.size);

            this.objectStorageArray = newObjectStorageArray;
            this.weightStorageArray = newWeightStorageArray;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The second probability distribution data structure relies on a linked list, and provides the following operation:

- element addition in ammortized constant time,
- element removal in constant time,
- element sampling in worst-case linear time.

The data structure follows:

**LinkedListProbabilityDistribution.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.stat.support;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.stat.AbstractProbabilityDistribution;

/**
 * This class implements a probability distribution relying on a linked list.
 * The running times of the main methods are as follows:
 * 
 * <table>
 * <tr><td>Method</td>  <td>Complexity</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>addElement   </tt></td>  
 *     <td><tt>amortized constant time</tt>,</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>sampleElement</tt> </td>  <td><tt>O(n)</tt>,</td></tr>
 * <tr><td><tt>removeElement</tt> </td>  <td><tt>O(1)</tt>.</td></tr>
 * </table>
 * 
 * This probability distribution class is best used whenever it is modified
 * frequently compared to the number of queries made.
 * 
 * @param <E> the actual type of the elements stored in this probability 
 *            distribution.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 11, 2016)
 */
public class LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<E>
extends AbstractProbabilityDistribution<E> {

    private static final class LinkedListNode<E> {

        private final E element;
        private final double weight;
        private LinkedListNode<E> prev;
        private LinkedListNode<E> next;

        LinkedListNode(final E element, final double weight) {
            this.element = element;
            this.weight  = weight;
        }

        E getElement() {
            return this.element;
        }

        double getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
        }

        LinkedListNode<E> getPreviousLinkedListNode() {
            return this.prev;
        }

        LinkedListNode<E> getNextLinkedListNode() {
            return this.next;
        }

        void setPreviousLinkedListNode(final LinkedListNode<E> node) {
            this.prev = node;
        }

        void setNextLinkedListNode(final LinkedListNode<E> node) {
            this.next = node;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This map maps the elements to their respective linked list nodes.
     */
    private final Map<E, LinkedListNode<E>> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Stores the very first linked list node in this probability distribution.
     */
    private LinkedListNode<E> linkedListHead;

    /**
     * Stores the very last linked list node in this probability distribution.
     */
    private LinkedListNode<E> linkedListTail;

    /**
     * Construct a new probability distribution. 
     */
    public LinkedListProbabilityDistribution() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new probability distribution using the input random number
     * generator.
     * 
     * @param random the random number generator to use.
     */
    public LinkedListProbabilityDistribution(final Random random) {
        super(random);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addElement(final E element, final double weight) {
        checkWeight(weight);

        if (this.map.containsKey(element)) {
            return false;
        }

        final LinkedListNode<E> newnode = new LinkedListNode<>(element, weight);

        if (linkedListHead == null) {
            linkedListHead = newnode;
            linkedListTail = newnode;
        } else {
            linkedListTail.setNextLinkedListNode(newnode);
            newnode.setPreviousLinkedListNode(linkedListTail);
            linkedListTail = newnode;
        }

        this.map.put(element, newnode);
        this.size++;
        this.totalWeight += weight;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public E sampleElement() {
        checkNotEmpty();
        double value = this.random.nextDouble() * this.totalWeight;

        for (LinkedListNode<E> node = linkedListHead;
                node != null;
                node = node.getNextLinkedListNode()) {
            if (value < node.getWeight()) {
                return node.getElement();
            }

            value -= node.getWeight();
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        return this.map.containsKey(element);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(E element) {
        final LinkedListNode<E> node = map.get(element);

        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }

        this.map.remove(element);
        this.size--;
        this.totalWeight -= node.getWeight();
        unlink(node);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.totalWeight = 0.0;
        this.map.clear();
        this.linkedListHead = null;
        this.linkedListTail = null;
    }

    private void unlink(final LinkedListNode<E> node) {
        final LinkedListNode<E> left  = node.getPreviousLinkedListNode();
        final LinkedListNode<E> right = node.getNextLinkedListNode();

        if (left != null) {
            left.setNextLinkedListNode(node.getNextLinkedListNode());
        } else {
            this.linkedListHead = node.getNextLinkedListNode();
        }

        if (right != null) {
            right.setPreviousLinkedListNode(node.getPreviousLinkedListNode());
        } else {
            this.linkedListTail = node.getPreviousLinkedListNode();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The third data structure relies on a binary tree and runs all the three main methods in worst-case logarithmic time. It looks like this:

[image: Tree]

Above, the red nodes are the leaf nodes containing the actual elements. White nodes are called in the code *relay nodes*. The integers in each node denote how many leaf nodes a particular relay node contains, and the real numbers denote the sum of weights of all the leaves of a relay node.

The data structure follows:

**BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.stat.support;

import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.stat.AbstractProbabilityDistribution;

/**
 * This class implements a probability distribution relying on a binary tree
 * structure. It allows <tt>O(log n)</tt> worst case time for adding, removing
 * and sampling an element.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 11, 2016)
 * @param <E> the actual type of the elements stored in this distribution.
 */
public class BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<E>
extends AbstractProbabilityDistribution<E> {

    private static final class Node<E> {

        /**
         * Holds the element if this block is a leaf. Internal blocks have 
         * {@code null} assigned to this field.
         */
        private final E element;

        /**
         * If this block is a leaf, specifies the weight of the {@code element}.
         * Otherwise, this field caches the sum of all weights over all
         * descendant leaves.
         */
        private double weight;

        private boolean isRelayNode;

        /**
         * The left child node.
         */
        private Node<E> leftChild;

        /**
         * The right child node.
         */
        private Node<E> rightChild;

        /**
         * The parent node.
         */
        private Node<E> parent;

        /**
         * Caches the number of leaf nodes in the subtree starting from this
         * node.
         */
        private int numberOfLeafNodes;

        Node(final E element, final double weight) {
            this.element = element;
            this.weight  = weight;
            this.numberOfLeafNodes = 1;
        }   

        Node() {
            this.element = null;
            this.isRelayNode = true;
        }

        public String toString() {
            if (this.isRelayNode) {
                return "[" + String.format("%.3f", this.getWeight()) +
                       " : " + this.numberOfLeafNodes + "]";
            }

            return "(" + String.format("%.3f", this.getWeight()) + 
                   " : " + this.element + ")";
        }

        E getElement() {
            return this.element;
        }

        double getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
        }

        void setWeight(final double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        int getNumberOfLeaves() {
            return this.numberOfLeafNodes;
        }

        void setNumberOfLeaves(final int numberOfLeaves) {
            this.numberOfLeafNodes = numberOfLeaves;
        }

        Node<E> getLeftChild() {
            return this.leftChild;
        }

        void setLeftChild(final Node<E> block) {
            this.leftChild = block;
        }

        Node<E> getRightChild() {
            return this.rightChild;
        }

        void setRightChild(final Node<E> block) {
            this.rightChild = block;
        }

        Node<E> getParent() {
            return this.parent;
        }

        void setParent(final Node<E> block) {
            this.parent = block;
        }

        boolean isRelayNode() {
            return isRelayNode;
        }

        boolean isLeafNode() {
            return !isRelayNode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Maps each element to the list of nodes representing the element.
     */
    private final Map<E, Node<E>> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * The root node of this distribution tree.
     */
    private Node<E> root;

    /**
     * Constructs this probability distribution using a default random number
     * generator.
     */
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution() {
        this(new Random());
    }

    /**
     * Constructs this probability distribution using the input random number
     * generator.
     * 
     * @param random the random number generator to use. 
     */
    public BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(final Random random) {
        super(random);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addElement(E element, double weight) {
        checkWeight(weight);

        if (this.map.containsKey(element)) {
            return false;
        }

        final Node<E> newnode = new Node<>(element, weight);
        insert(newnode);
        this.size++;
        this.totalWeight += weight;
        this.map.put(element, newnode);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        return this.map.containsKey(element);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public E sampleElement() {
        checkNotEmpty();

        double value = this.totalWeight * this.random.nextDouble();
        Node<E> node = root;

        while (node.isRelayNode()) {
            if (value < node.getLeftChild().getWeight()) {
                node = node.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                value -= node.getLeftChild().getWeight();
                node = node.getRightChild();
            }
        }

        return node.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(final E element) {
        final Node<E> node = this.map.get(element);

        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }

        delete(node);
        updateMetadata(node.getParent(), -node.getWeight(), -1);
        this.size--;
        this.totalWeight -= node.getWeight();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc } 
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.root = null;
        this.size = 0;
        this.totalWeight = 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * Assuming that {@code leafNodeToBypass} is a leaf node, this procedure 
     * attaches a relay node instead of it, and assigns {@code leafNodeToBypass}
     * and {@code newnode} as children of the new relay node.
     * 
     * @param leafNodeToBypass the leaf node to bypass.
     * @param newNode          the new node to add.
     */
    private void bypassLeafNode(final Node<E> leafNodeToBypass, 
                                final Node<E> newNode) {
        final Node<E> relayNode = new Node<>();
        final Node<E> parentOfCurrentNode = leafNodeToBypass.getParent();

        relayNode.setNumberOfLeaves(1);
        relayNode.setWeight(leafNodeToBypass.getWeight());
        relayNode.setLeftChild(leafNodeToBypass);
        relayNode.setRightChild(newNode);

        leafNodeToBypass.setParent(relayNode);
        newNode.setParent(relayNode);

        if (parentOfCurrentNode == null) {
            this.root = relayNode;
        } else if (parentOfCurrentNode.getLeftChild() == leafNodeToBypass) {
            relayNode.setParent(parentOfCurrentNode);
            parentOfCurrentNode.setLeftChild(relayNode);
        } else {
            relayNode.setParent(parentOfCurrentNode);
            parentOfCurrentNode.setRightChild(relayNode);
        }

        updateMetadata(relayNode, newNode.getWeight(), 1);
    }

    private void insert(final Node<E> node) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        Node<E> currentNode = root;

        while (currentNode.isRelayNode()) {
            if (currentNode.getLeftChild().getNumberOfLeaves() < 
                    currentNode.getRightChild().getNumberOfLeaves()) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getRightChild();
            }
        }

        bypassLeafNode(currentNode, node);
    }

    private void delete(final Node<E> leafToDelete) {
        final Node<E> relayNode = leafToDelete.getParent();

        if (relayNode == null) {
            this.root = null;
            return;
        } 

        final Node<E> parentOfRelayNode = relayNode.getParent();
        final Node<E> siblingLeaf = relayNode.getLeftChild() == leafToDelete ?
                                    relayNode.getRightChild() :
                                    relayNode.getLeftChild();

        if (parentOfRelayNode == null) {
            this.root = siblingLeaf;
            siblingLeaf.setParent(null);
            return;
        }

        if (parentOfRelayNode.getLeftChild() == relayNode) {
            parentOfRelayNode.setLeftChild(siblingLeaf);
        } else {
            parentOfRelayNode.setRightChild(siblingLeaf);
        }

        siblingLeaf.setParent(parentOfRelayNode);
    }

    /**
     * This method is responsible for updating the metadata of this data 
     * structure.
     * 
     * @param node      the node from which to start the metadata update. The 
     *                  updating routine updates also the metadata of all the 
     *                  predecessors of this node in the tree.
     * @param weight    the weight delta to add to each predecessor node.
     * @param nodeDelta the node count delta to add to each predecessor node.
     */
    private void updateMetadata(Node<E> node, 
                                final double weightDelta, 
                                final int nodeDelta) {
        while (node != null) {
            node.setNumberOfLeaves(node.getNumberOfLeaves() + nodeDelta);
            node.setWeight(node.getWeight() + weightDelta);
            node = node.getParent();
        }
    }

    public String debugToString() {
        if (root == null) {
            return "empty";
        }

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final int treeHeight = getTreeHeight(root);
        final Deque<Node<E>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.addLast(root);

        for (int i = 0; i < treeHeight + 1; ++i) {
            int currentQueueLength = queue.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < currentQueueLength; ++j) {
                final Node<E> node = queue.removeFirst();
                addChildren(node, queue);
                sb.append(node == null ? "null" : node.toString()).append(" ");
            }

            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void addChildren(final Node<E> node, final Deque<Node<E>> queue) {
        if (node == null) {
            queue.addLast(null);
            queue.addLast(null);
            return;
        }

        queue.addLast(node.getLeftChild());
        queue.addLast(node.getRightChild());
    }

    private int getTreeHeight(final Node<E> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 1 + Math.max(getTreeHeight(node.getLeftChild()),
                            getTreeHeight(node.getRightChild()));
    }
}
```

---

Finally, the demo (I don't want to get reviewed) is...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import net.coderodde.stat.AbstractProbabilityDistribution;
import net.coderodde.stat.support.ArrayProbabilityDistribution;
import net.coderodde.stat.support.BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution;
import net.coderodde.stat.support.LinkedListProbabilityDistribution;

public class Demo {

    private static final int DISTRIBUTION_SIZE = 20_000;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("[DEMO] BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution:");
        binaryTreeProbabilityDistributionDemo();

        System.out.println("[STATUS] Warming up...");
        warmup();
        System.out.println("[STATUS] Warming up done!");
        System.out.println();

        AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> arraypd = 
                new ArrayProbabilityDistribution<>();

        AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> listpd = 
                new LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<>();

        AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> treepd =
                new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<>();

        profile(arraypd);
        profile(listpd);
        profile(treepd);
    }

    private static void binaryTreeProbabilityDistributionDemo() {
        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<Integer> pd = 
                new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<>();

        pd.addElement(0, 1.0);
        pd.addElement(1, 1.0);
        pd.addElement(2, 1.0);
        pd.addElement(3, 3.0);

        int[] counts = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            Integer myint = pd.sampleElement();
            counts[myint]++;
            System.out.println(myint);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
    }

    private static void 
        profile(final AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> pd) {
        final Random random = new Random();

        System.out.println("[" + pd.getClass().getSimpleName() + "]:");

        long totalDuration = 0L;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < DISTRIBUTION_SIZE; ++i) {
            pd.addElement(i, 10.0 * random.nextDouble());
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("addElement() in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                           " milliseconds.");
        totalDuration += (endTime - startTime);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < DISTRIBUTION_SIZE; ++i) {
            pd.sampleElement();
        }

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("sampleElement() in " + (endTime - startTime) +
                           " milliseconds.");
        totalDuration += (endTime - startTime);

        final List<Integer> contents = new ArrayList<>(DISTRIBUTION_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < DISTRIBUTION_SIZE; ++i) {
            contents.add(i);
        }

        shuffle(contents);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (Integer i : contents) {
            pd.removeElement(i);
        }

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("removeElement() in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                           " milliseconds.");

        totalDuration += (endTime - startTime);

        System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalDuration + 
                           " milliseconds.");

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void shuffle(final List<Integer> list) {
        final Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            final int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
            final Integer integer = list.get(index);
            list.set(index, list.get(i));
            list.set(i, integer);
        }
    }

    private static void warmup() {
        final long seed =35214717058750L; System.nanoTime();
        final Random inputRandom1 = new Random(seed);
        final Random inputRandom2 = new Random(seed);
        final Random inputRandom3 = new Random(seed);

        final AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> pd1 = 
             new ArrayProbabilityDistribution<>(inputRandom1);

        final AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> pd2 = 
             new LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<>(inputRandom2);

        final AbstractProbabilityDistribution<Integer> pd3 =
             new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<>(inputRandom3);

        final Random random = new Random(seed);
        final List<Integer> content = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);

        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 100_000; ++iteration) {
            final double coin = random.nextDouble();

            if (coin < 0.3) {
                // Add a new element.
                final Integer element = random.nextInt();
                final double weight = 30.0 * random.nextDouble();
                content.add(element);

                pd1.addElement(element, weight);
                pd2.addElement(element, weight);
                pd3.addElement(element, weight);
            } else if (coin < 0.5) {
                // Remove an element.
                if (!pd1.isEmpty()) {
                    final Integer element = choose(content, random);

                    pd1.removeElement(element);
                    pd2.removeElement(element);
                    pd3.removeElement(element);
                    content.remove(element);
                }
            } else if (!pd1.isEmpty()) {
                // Sample elements:
                pd1.sampleElement();
                pd2.sampleElement();
                pd3.sampleElement();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Integer choose(final List<Integer> list, 
                                  final Random random) {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

---

The performance figures are as follows:

```
[STATUS] Warming up...
Seed = 35214717058750
[STATUS] Warming up done!

[ArrayProbabilityDistribution]:
addElement() in 8 milliseconds.
sampleElement() in 321 milliseconds.
removeElement() in 500 milliseconds.
Total duration: 829 milliseconds.

[LinkedListProbabilityDistribution]:
addElement() in 7 milliseconds.
sampleElement() in 1184 milliseconds.
removeElement() in 9 milliseconds.
Total duration: 1200 milliseconds.

[BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution]:
addElement() in 24 milliseconds.
sampleElement() in 15 milliseconds.
removeElement() in 16 milliseconds.
Total duration: 55 milliseconds.
```

**Critique request**

I would like to hear the comments regarding the following:

- API design,
- naming conventions,
- coding conventions,
- performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Inconsistent use of `this`

I'm not sure why you used a `this` prefix for many of your variables, when it was optional to do so.  I would have omitted it myself.  But assuming you had a reason for doing so, you didn't do it consistently.  It seems like around 70% of the places use it and 30% don't.

#### Array implementation suggestion

You could modify your Array implementation to do the following:

1. In addition to storing an array of objects and an array of weights, you could make a third array which stores cumulative weights.  In other words, `cumulativeWeight[n]` would be the sum of `weightStorageArray[i]` for `i = 0..n`.
2. With the cumulative weight array, `sampleElement()` could now be done using a binary search through the cumulative weight array.  This reduces sample time to \$O(\log n)\$ instead of \$O(n)\$.
3. Adding an element remains constant time because you can compute the cumulative weight of the new element in constant time like this:

   ```
   cumulativeWeight[this.size] = weight +
                                 (this.size == 0) ? 0 : cumulativeWeight[this.size-1];
   ```
4. Removing an element still takes linear time, and you will need to adjust each element of `cumulativeWeight` as you shift it downwards.

This implemenation would potentially be superior to the binary tree implementation if removals were expected to be rare.

Comment: Benchmarked the binary search version: you are right; adding 4 times faster + sampling 2 times faster.

Comment: What comes to the (inconsistent) usage of **`this`**, I am still not sure what my coding conventions should be, so I am still experimenting with it.