# Weighted random selection

Tags: python, performance

> If given two lists a: ['the', 'a', 'and', 'for'] and b: [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1], the positions of the numbers in b represents the weights for the respective probabilities of obtaining the corresponding word. E.g. the : 20%, a : 30%, etc. Create a function that will generate words based on their corresponding probabilities.

**My solution:**

```
import random
def weighted_word_selection(words, weights):
    """ 
    words : an array of strings (words) 
    weights : an array of floats (corresponding probabilties based on)
              index number.
    """
    start = 0
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        weights[i] = start+weights[i]
        start += weights[i]
    r = random.uniform(0, 1.0)
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        if r < weights[i]:
            return words[i]
```

**Questions:**

1. What are some alternative ways to solve this, bearing in mind the requirement to optimize performance as the array words and the array weights approaches a large n? Any detailed explanations of underlying processes such as Cython/C based Python solutions are helpful.
2. Can you discuss the \$O(n)\$ based complexity of the problem and some performance issues in my solution, and how those are addressed in your suggested solution at scale?

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132088/comparing-three-data-structures-for-dealing-with-probability-distributions-in-ja). Its main result is a data structure for probability distribution that runs insert, delete and sample operations in \$\Theta(\log n)\$.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably an error in your first `for` loop:

```
    weights[i] = start+weights[i]
    start += weights[i]
```

as the resulting value of `start` (BTW not very descriptive name) will be increased *twice* by `weights[i]`, so the fix may be

```
    start += weights[i]
    weights[i] = start
```

---

But anyway, why you accumulate weights of individual words and moreover you assign the final result (which will be always `1`, of course) in the `start` variable, if you never use it? IMHO your program perform something other than you want.

---

As your two input lists correspond one to other, why not use the `zip()` function to make pairs of corresponding values:

```
word_weights = zip(words, weights)
```

and use it in your `for` loops?

---

Why don't utilize the `enumerate()` function for obtaining indices without any effort?